# Hiding charts in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I need to hide or show charts depending on the selected value, but it is not working and not showing the error in console. I made the javascript code with an alert and it works, so I guess the problem is not about the "if" logic

Here is the HTML code

```
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Left col -->
    <section class="col-lg-12 connectedSortable">
      <!-- Custom tabs (Charts with tabs)-->
      <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
        <!-- Tabs within a box -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right">

          <li class="active"><a href="#revenue-chart" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>

        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content no-padding">
          <!-- Morris chart - Sales -->
          <div class="chart tab-pane active" id="revenue-chart" style="position: relative; height: 300px;"></div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
  </div>

        <select class="target" id="opcion">
            <option value="mes1" selected="selected">Hace 1 mes</option>
            <option value="mes2">Hace 2 meses</option>
            <option value="mes3">Hace 3 meses</option>
        </select>
```

and this is the Javascript Snippet

```
  $( ".target" ).change(function() {
      if(document.getElementById('opcion').value == "mes1") {
          $('.box ul.nav a').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
              area.redraw();
              area2.hidden = true;
          });
      }
      if(document.getElementById('opcion').value == "mes2") {
          $('.box ul.nav a').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
              area2.redraw();
              area.hidden = true;
          });
      }
      if(document.getElementById('opcion').value == "mes3") {
          alert( "Mes 3" );
      }

  });
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: First of all, if you're using jQuery - use jQuery! Why do you need this : `document.getElementById` ? Replace it with `$("#opcion").val()` to get the value.

Comment: The example is not full. It's not clear what `area` and `area2` are and if there exist such event `shown.bs.tab`. Also, are you getting any JS errors in the console?

Comment: Thank you John, I replaced the getElementById tag with the one you said, and I'm editing the example for you to get the whole picture

Comment: I'm not getting any JS errors in console

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the chart js function called "Redraw". Thanks anyways